# Not able to create war file in netbeans

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans-7

Hello I am trying to create a war file in netbeans7.0 but I am not able to create it. It is showing following error

```
 Deleting directory C:\Documents and Settings\a\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ABC\build
 C:\Documents and Settings\a\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ABC\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1109: Unable to delete file C:\Documents and Settings\a\My      Documents\NetBeansProjects\ABC\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\asm-3.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically happens when trying to clean before the build, and GlassFish has a lock on a file that needs to be deleted in the clean process.

Try just doing build (without clean), or shut down GlassFish and then clean and build.

Comment: Thanks @barbeau I deleted existing war file now its working properly